# Cant publish ROS time on Clock topic after switching from Kinetic to Melodic

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had code running on Kinetic that published to a a simulated time on a topic named `/clock`. When I try compile the code using Melodic I get an error. The code I used to publish the simulated time was as follows:

```
ros::Time currentTime_;
currentTime_ += ros::Duration(dt_secs);
clockPub_ = node_.advertise<rosgraph_msgs::Clock>("/clock",1);
clockPub_.publish(currentTime_);
```

This code compiled and worked fine in Kinetic. However in Melodic I get the error:

```
 error: ‘const class ros::Time’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
     return m.__getMD5Sum().c_str();
 error: ‘const class ros::Time’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’
     return m.__getDataType().c_str();
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381407/cant-publish-ros-time-on-clock-topic-after-switching-from-kinetic-to-melodic/) by [Watchdog101](https://answers.ros.org/users/76862/watchdog101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution to this. My assumption is that ROS Kinetic allowed for the conversion from messages `ros::Time` to `rosgraph_msgs::Clock`, while ROS melodic does not. Thus the solution is to first manually convert the `ros::Time` message to a `rosgraph_msgs::Clock` message. You can do that as follows:

```
ros::Time currentTime_;
rosgraph_msgs::Clock msg;
currentTime_ += ros::Duration(dt_secs);
msg.time = currentTime_;
clockPub_ = node_.advertise<rosgraph_msgs::Clock>("/clock",1);
clockPub_.publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [Watchdog101](https://answers.ros.org/users/76862/watchdog101/) with karma: 16 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-07-01**:
The automatic type conversion like that is often provided in header files via templates. I would be surprised if that capability went away. However it's likely that you were relying on that capability via a transitive dependency which was cleaned up between Kinetic and Melodic.

**Comment by [Watchdog101](https://answers.ros.org/users/76862/watchdog101/) on 2021-07-01**:
Interesting, thanks for the additional info. The error was thrown from a package which wasn't mine, so it would take me some time to dig through it and fully understand all dependencies. None the less, a good point for anyone else who runs into similar issues.